# Open Source Java Reporting Framework

Tags: java, reporting, jasper-reports, pentaho, birt

i want to create few Reports which picks data from few SQL tables, So instead of creating different report's i want to create (or use any Open source) reporting framework, I googled about it but still didn't find enough information to try one.

Following are my requirements:

```
  Filters : Support for different types of Filtering mechanism for the End User
  DataSource : SQL Table
  UI :  user Defined UI for every user (user specific information can be persisted in DB)
  Number of concurrent users : 10 (Max)
  server : tomcat
  Support for graph/Charts
  javascript support for customizable UI
```

i have heard about Jasper / birt framework but dont have working knowledge for any 1 of them so can some one suggest if there exists a opensource framework which i can use for the above mentioned requirements

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are the tools around the JasperReports library like iReport and JasperServer all from [JasperSoft](http://www.jaspersoft.com/). The tools around [Eclipse Birt](http://eclipse.org/birt/). And then there are the tools from [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/).

All three are very powerful and open source and can do what you need. There is plenty of tooling and documentation available and you can buy commercial support for them. Your decision will be based a bit around licensing and potential need for features that are only in the commercial version (e.g. of JasperServer).

Comment: Thanks for pointing on Birt. Compared it with Jasper and came to the conclusion, that it is much more intuitive and less buggy, than Jasper. IReports are too inconvenient in design. Also Pentaho is not free, it has free addition, but it is too limited

Comment: Pentaho Reporting (Engine and Report Designer + the ability to run these on the server) is 100% free in Pentaho. I have no clue where you read that Pentaho would not be free in that respect.

Interactive-Reporting is NOT free, in the same way certain features in JasperSoft's servers are not free (or for that respect, in the same way you are asked to buy Actuate's reporting product if you want support and additional enterprise features). In that respect all vendors follow the same strategy.

Comment: I agree.. to some degree all three are using the open source version as bait to get into the commercial support and tooling. Thats why it is important to check if you like the commercial side of things even if you just need the open source features at the moment. Also the licenses are different and that might have an impact (LGPL/GPL, ASL, EPL).

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements can be met with both JasperReports and BIRT frameworks.

Consider trying [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport), which is a very mature graphical designer for JasperReports. I must warn you though, iReport is highly addictive ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation. First I tried Jasper (Ireport for GUI jasperreport design), but it was too inconvenient and non-intuitive. I tried Birt and it works perfectly. You should start from this demo:

http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/examples/misc/BIRT2.1Demo/EclipseDemo.html

, it's very good in clarifying how to work and implement reports in Eclipse. Also Birt plugin for Eclipse contains very good interactive helpers - just add the report template and follow steps from interactive helper. Very useful.

You can also try different demos for iReport: 
http://ireport-tutorial.blogspot.com/2008/10/ireport-parameterized-report.html